# firemonkey tmapview custom tile server

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have my own tile server and like to use tmapview component

Is it possible to use tmapview with my own tile server ??

like tileoverlay

thanks

Comment: There is no published property for specifying custom tile server, so I doubt that without a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMapView is specifically for maps via the Google Maps API, which means it is tied specifically to Google. From the [TMapView documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Maps.TMapView) (**emphasis added**):

> To run an application on Android with TMapView, **you need to acquire an API-Key for Google Maps API**.

So no, you cannot use it with your own server.

Comment: Though it was not that difficult to think about a "more" common class design (there are existing ones, not for Delphi, but exists)..

Comment: @Victoria: Unfortunately, EMBT didn't think that way. TMapView was  designed 100% with Google  Maps in mind.

Comment: Thanks everyone
@Victoria could you please contact me about your map viewer

Comment: @user3511007, sure, but I'm not the property owner of that source (I don't even have access to it now). But we are in contact and he promised that we can release it as supported open source this year (a lot of payed work has been done on it) and I hope it will satisfy many dev. requirements (it's flexible, efficient in tile serving, full of animated stuff, ready for custom layers like real time router, custom data etc.). So at this time I'd ask you for patience. Besides, it's only for Windows (though dependencies like e.g. SQLite, Geos and others might be portable).